# BHO does not display messagebox in 64bit machine

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, dll, 32bit-64bit, bho

I have implemented BHO in 32bit machine. It is working fine in my machine. and I have found 2 observations.

1. BHO Setup run on 64 bit machine which has .net framework - worked perfectly. displays messagebox on `OnBeforeNavigate2` event.
2. BHO Setup on 64 machine w/o .net framework. installed .net framework manually and run setup. It is installing perfectly. when I open IE, it gives me a popup to enable BHO. but, it does not show messagebox. :(

I would like to know where there is a problem in framework related issue, why messagebox is not working? or I have to include any assembly manually. If yes, I would like to know which assembly is missing in that case. I have tried with dependency walker but no clue what is actually missing - no error in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to post an answer on my question.

After few research and trials of different ways to run BHO in 64bit IE, I have found a solution.

To run BHO in 64bit IE, you must need to register BHO with 64bit regsvr32.exe NOT 32bit.

bydefault, 32bit regsvr32.exe runs everytime
so we go at particular location of regsvr32 and run the command
by this way, It will work.

```
%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe
```

this is the easiest way to hit the command (work for both systems 64bit and 32bit).

Hope if helps for your problem also.